How can I properly display data in debugging Rust in RustRover?
I'm using RustRover for some Rust programming. However debugging does work as expected.
In Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Data Views -> Rust there are 3 options for LLDB renderers. I have tried all 3 of them and below are the results. The data I try to read is simple Vec<char>:
Bundled renderers: 
Rust compiler's renderers: 
No renderers: 
All I want to see is the vector content!
My setup is:

Mac with Apple M3 Max chip
MacOS Sequoia 15.1.1
RustRover 2024.1.8


Do you know what the content is (e.g. from printing it)? In particular, is it composed of printable characters or unprintable characters?

Definitely printable characters. This is the simpliest example possible and I made it myself. In this case it is vector or dots (.). It's not like it doesn't work for some specific case - it doesn't work for any vector, or any other dynamic data. All it shows correctly are variables of primitive types which makes the debugger quite useless.

Update to 2024.3.1 helped. Bundled renderers work fine!
